# Goldfish laying at an arch- what should I do?

Tags: fish, diseases, goldfish

[image]

I have one common goldfish in a 20 gallon tank with a filter and heater. She has been sitting in this arch position for about 4 hours with little to no improvement (couple of little energy bursts). I have attached the water test results to get an idea. For the past 5 weeks she has been struggling on and off to swim properly and I don’t know what to do. I have been feeding her peas and changing the water more frequently with aquarium salt. I need to know what to quick because she isn’t doing so great. Help

Comment: Hi Emma did you ever get a diagnosis for your fish? I have a common that is suffering from something that sounds similar to this and can't find any information anywhere!